# Handling event order differences between IE and Chrome/FF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuggling since days with a problem depending on the fact that event order is different in IE to Chrome and FF.
I build a customized checkbox which is able to have three states: checked, not checked and indeterminate. On 'click' starts a script which change the state. Additional I need the 'Change' event to do things depending on the state of the checkbox.

In Chrome it works like a charm: first 'click' fires -> script changes the state -> then 'change' fires -> something happens for new state.

In IE is the event order different: First 'change' fires -> something happen for current state -> 'click' fires as second -> state changed.

I tried to use 'mouseup' event which fires always before 'change' in all browsers. But it dont fires on the checkbox label elements, just on the checkbox itself.

Additional in my situation: the original checkbox is hidden and replaced by a designed one. So the user even cant click the original checkbox itself.

I use jquery and its widget factory for this customized checkbox.

How I can handle the needed events in the neccessary order: click -> change

Thx for your ideas!!
Mike

Comment: here is an old fiddle to an early checkbox script of mine
https://jsfiddle.net/mikexmagic/3wohfyk6/36/